# Angular2 nested resolvers with RXjs store race conditions

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am back with and interesting dilemma. I am building an angular2 app and using RXjs observable data stores to feed my app with data. Namely on launch, if the user is logged in, the app resolvers in angular fetch the logged in user data and then push it to the stores, which in turn feed that data to the parts of the app that only a logged in user can see. This means, for example, that the JWT token that the user is authenticated with, also lives in the store.

routing example

```
{
    path: '',
    resolve: {
        _: AppResolverService
    },
    children: [
        path: 'subnav',
        resolve: {
            _: SubnavResolverService
        }
    ]
}
```

Observe how the resolvers are nested, wherein the

AppResolverService

If user is logged in then fetches JWT token and other user data and sends it to the Session Store Data service. Otherwise user is redirected to login.

code example:

```
let resolverObservable = this._sharedOrchestrationService.getLoggedInUser();
resolverObservable
    .subscribe( (res:UserModel) => {
        this._sessionStoreService.setLoggedInUser( res )
});

return resolverObservable;
```

SubnavResolverService

Fetches user credentials from the Session Store Data Service

code example:

```
let ret = this._dashboardOrchestrationService.getUserListings( 
    this._sessionStoreService.loggedInUserLastValue.id 
);
```

SessionStore

code example:

```
setLoggedInUser( _loggedInUser: UserModel ) : Observable<UserModel> { 
    this._loggedInUser.next( _loggedInUser );
    return this._loggedInUser.asObservable();
}
```

Problem officer?

The problem is that as you can see the session store uses an observable data service and since the AppResolver is pushing that observable data and it is an asynchronous function then there is a 50% chance that the SubnavResolverService starts to request data with an undefined user, because the AppResolver has finished, but the SessionStore is still running the data pushing.

What I am trying to achieve here?

Can the AppResolver be somehow delayed for eg. 200ms after it has received the user data and is trying to set it in sessionStore? So that when it resolves, I can be certain that the user data is safely stored in the stores.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I just figured out 1 solution.

In the AppResolverService, where the Observable is returned, I added an RXjs delay() modifier, so that the resolver is delayed, but session store has time to process it's updates.

```
return resolverObservable.delay( (new Date(Date.now() + 200)) );
```

this delays the resolver 200ms.

I am open to other solutions also, please elaborate guys!